# Does @param args in java do anything?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I create a new java class in eclipse, it adds the @param args in comments. Does this actually do anything, or can it just be deleted?

```
public class Example {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with JavaDoc

Comment: It's usefull for JavaDoc.

Comment: It can be used to create JavaDoc. But in code, no, it doesn't affect anything so you can remove it. Take a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#@param

Comment: Before starting to learn JavaDoc, learn the basics of comments.

Comment: seriously I bet it took you more time to write this question, rather than do a google search.

Comment: @nafas interesting point: https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&hl=en&q=%40param+java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may automatically create documentation for your classes/methods/fields with a tool named `Javadoc`. And this type of comments is for this documentation. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html